# PHP - number_format fails with math operations

Tags: php, number-formatting

The PHP function `number_format` produces weird results when using it with math operations.

Run this...

```
echo number_format(32545000 - 24343400) . '<br>';
echo number_format(32545000) - number_format(24343400);
```

Why does the second one produce an answer of "8" instead of the correct answer?

Comment: You don't want to be using `-` with strings. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`number_format(32545000)` returns a string: 32,545,000

`number_format(24343400)` returns a string: 24,343,400

The strings are converted to int and you get:

`32 - 24 = 8`

Comment: Ok.  But why wouldn't this work: `echo intval(number_format(32545000)) - intval(number_format(24343400));`

Comment: @gtilflm this code gives exactly the same result. `number_format` formats a number into a print-friendly format. Why would you subtract strings instead of doing `32545000 - 24343400`?